# Condense multiple if statements

Tags: python

Right now my python code looks like this:

```
if imput == "con":
    print "%.6f" % (con_getinfo["balance"])
elif imput == "xra":
    print "%.6f" % (xra_getinfo["balance"])
elif imput == "neg":
    print "%.6f" % (neg_getinfo["balance"])
elif imput == "grf":
    print "%.6f" % (grf_getinfo["balance"])
elif imput == "ninja":
    print "%.6f" % (ninja_getinfo["balance"])
```

Now i would like it to make it look less repetitive, like this:

```
if imput == con or imput == xra or imput == neg or imput == grf or imput == ninja:
```

But i can't figure out how to assign to each of the conditions the proper reaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store references to the functions in a dictionary, then it's just a simple lookup:

```
response = {
    "con": con_getinfo,
    "neg": neg_getinfo,
    ...
}
print "%.6f" % (response[imput]["balance"])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is arguably a dupe, but in a nutshell... the pythonic way is to use a dictionary.  There are probably better ways to refactor this, but to start:

```
mydict = {"con": con_getinfo,
          "xra": xra_getinfo,
          "neg": neg_getinfo,
          "grf": grf_getinfo,
          "ninja" : ninja_getinfo}

lookup = mydict.get(imput)
if lookup: #won't fail if imput isn't on of the options
    print "%.6f" % (lookup["balance"])
```